# If $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = \infty$, then $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x) dx$ is divergent.

Tags: calculus, limits, improper-integrals

Is this result true in the first place (or would it correct to say that $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x) dx = \infty$ as well)? If so, could I have a hint on how to prove it?

Intuitively, thinking along the lines of Riemann sums it seems like this may make sense. I was also trying to think of counterexamples but was unable to come up with one (taking into account common polynomials, composites of trigonometric functions).

Comment: My **blind guess**, which could easily **be wrong** is that it depends on whether, for any finite $b$, the $\int_0^b f(x)dx$ is finite.  T

Comment: @user2661923 Note the question says that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan +1 good catch.  I think that it is better to leave my my 1st comment in place, illustrating my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Note the definition of limits means that with

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = \infty \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

then for *every* $M \in \mathbb{R}$, there's an $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) \gt M \; \forall \; x \gt x_0$. What does this tell you about what you can compare the value of $\int_{x_0}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ against to determine whether or not it diverges to infinity?

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I am still a little unclear about what you mean in your prompt, especially the part on how to 'compare the value of $\int_{x_0}^{\infty}f(x)$ ' to come to the divergent conclusion. Did you mean I can directly apply the definition of limits to a function representing the integral, i.e $F(x) = \int_{x_0}^{x}f(x)$ and perform the steps to prove $\lim_{x \to \infty}F(x) = \infty$?

Comment: @iobtl Since $f(x) \gt M$, then for any $x \gt x_0$, you have $\int_{x_0}^{x}f(t)dt \gt \int_{x_0}^{x}Mdt = M(x - x_0)$. What happens with this inequality for any $M \gt 0$ when you take the limit as $x$ goes to infinity, e.g., your $F(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty}\int_{x_0}^{x}f(t)dt$ (note I replaced the integration variable with $t$ to avoid duplicating it with the $x$ outside of it)? In other words, what you wrote above is basically what I was trying to indicate, but since you stated you only wanted a hint, I didn't go into more details in my answer.

Comment: I understand now. Your mention of the inequality for $\int_{x_0}^{x}f(t) dt > M(x-x_0)$ reminded me of this important concept for integrals of continuous functions. Thank you!